# Can you make mushroom houses reappear?

Tags: super-mario-3d-land

In New Super Mario Bros, once you cleared all levels in the game any mushroom house you've visited would reappear and won't disappear again, meaning you could get unlimited items at any time.

This doesn't seem to be the case in Super Mario 3D Land. I've completed the game including all the S-* worlds and collected every star coin, but the mushroom houses still aren't accessible. I know the purple challenge rooms respawn once daily or so or when using street pass, but that doesn't seem to be the case with musroom houses. Has anyone managed to make them reappear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I've gotten them to respawn is when I street pass with someone who doesn't own the game. When I street pass with a random person who hasn't played Super Mario 3D Land, I'll get a mushroom house instead of a new purple box room. Other then that I haven't seen them randomly respawn on their own.

Comment: That a bummer. I wish they worked like the DS game...